# How to delete data or table within two bookmarks from word document using OpenXml in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating word document in C# using OpenXML.
I can insert my Text after specified bookmark, but how can delete data within two bookmarks.

Following is the code to insert text after specified Bookmark.

```
 string fileName = @"C:\Users\sharepointadmin\Desktop\volc.docx";

            TableValues ObjTableValues = new TableValues();
            List<TableValues> allValues = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TableValues>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                ObjTableValues = new TableValues();
                ObjTableValues.EmpID = i.ToString();
                ObjTableValues.EmpName = "Emp" + i.ToString();
                ObjTableValues.EmpDesig = "SE";
                ObjTableValues.EmpDept = "Software";

                allValues.Add(ObjTableValues);
                //ConvertMailMergeEscape(fileName);

            }

            AddTable(fileName, allValues);

        }
            using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {
                IDictionary<String, BookmarkStart> bookmarkMap = new Dictionary<String, BookmarkStart>();               

                var doc = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;
                var mainpart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                var res = from ObjTableValues in mainpart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>() where ObjTableValues.Name == "testbookmark" select ObjTableValues;                
                var bookmark = res.SingleOrDefault();
                if (bookmark != null)
                {
                    var parent = bookmark.Parent;
 run.Append(text);
                    Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph(run);

                    // insert after bookmark parent
                    parent.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraph);
  foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in document.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
                {
                    bookmarkMap[bookmarkStart.Name] = bookmarkStart;
                }

                MoveToRangeStart ranstart = new MoveToRangeStart();


                foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in bookmarkMap.Values)
                {
                    Run bookmarkText = bookmarkStart.NextSibling<Run>();
                    if (bookmarkText != null)
                    {
                        //bookmarkText.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = "blah";
                    }
                }

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table table = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table();

                TableProperties props = new TableProperties(
                    new TableBorders(
                    new TopBorder
                    {
                        Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single),
                        Size = 12
                    },
                    new BottomBorder
                    {
                        Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single),
                        Size = 12
                    },
                    new LeftBorder
                    {
                        Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single),
                        Size = 12
                    },
                    new RightBorder
                    {
                        Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single),
                        Size = 12
                    },
                    new InsideHorizontalBorder
                    {
                        Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single),
                        Size = 12
                    },
                    new InsideVerticalBorder
                    {
                        Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Single),
                        Size = 12
                    }));

                table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(props);

                foreach (TableValues Tableitem in allValues)
                {
                    var tr = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow();

                    var tc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell();

                    tc.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(Tableitem.EmpID))));
                    tr.Append(tc);

                    tc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell();
                    tc.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(Tableitem.EmpName))));
                    tr.Append(tc);

                    tc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell();
                    tc.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(Tableitem.EmpDesig))));
                    tr.Append(tc);

                    tc = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell();
                    tc.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(Tableitem.EmpDept))));
                    tr.Append(tc);

                    table.Append(tr);

                }
                doc.Body.Append(table);
                doc.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to delete some table or data from word document. If this is the case than I will suggest you to enable the developer tab in Microsoft Word. For Microsoft Word 2007 if you click on Office Button and than go to "Word Options" button which is at the bottom of drop down menue. Now enable Show "Developer tab in The Ribbon".
Once you have activated the developer tab now you can see an additional tab "Developer" in your Microsoft Word. From this tab if you click on the Rich Text icon (Marked with **Aa**), will insert a tag on your word document. Now, If you right click on the tag, you can give this tag a name and id.

Now you can access this tag by its id or name in C#. 
e.g. the tag name you have given is 'Test Tag'

```
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    List<SdtBlock> taggedContentControls = mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtBlock>().ToList();
    foreach (var tagControl in taggedContentControls)
                    {
                        string tagName = tagControl.Descendants<SdtAlias>().First().Val.Value;
                        if(tagName== "Test Tag")
                        {
// you can insert any data in this tag over here
}
```

Now, with similar approach let's suppose you have a table and some other data in this tag that you want to delete

```
foreach (var tagControl in taggedContentControls)
                {
                    string tagName = tagControl.Descendants<SdtAlias>().First().Val.Value;
                    if (tagName.Contains("Test Tag"))
                    {
// If we want to delete table only
                        //tagControl.SdtContentBlock.Descendants<Table>().First().Remov();       
// If you want to remove everything in this tag                        
tagControl.SdtContentBlock.Remove();
                    }
                }
```

dont forget to save your document at the end of this operation
i mean mainpart.Document.Save();

for simplicity I have written multiple LINQ statements to fetch tag from the document. You can change them according to your understanding.

I hope it will help you to get your problem sorted.

Regards